# Use/create an equivalent for LogonUser function in Python

Tags: python, windows, authentication

Straight to the meat, I've been searching for a way to use the Windows [`LogonUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx) function within Python.

Having seen the usage of this function by a friend using C, I wanted to attempt a similar process with Python. Is there a way? or do I need to try to make that portion of script within C then somehow make my Python script call it?

Comment: What platform are you on? Are you working on Windows (where the OS provides it)? Or are you working on Linux, (where its something you want)?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the Windows API directly using `ctypes`:

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes
# create variable that will be filled with a token that represents the user
token = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE()
# 3 is LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, 0 is LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT
if ctypes.windll.advapi32.LogonUserW(u"username", u"domain", u"password", 3, 0, ctypes.byref(token)) == 0:
    # failed to login if we get 0
    failed_to_login()
# close the handle to avoid leaking it
ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(token)
```

You can also call `ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError()` after a failure to see what the error code was, which you can look up via `net helpmsg nnnn` in a command prompt.

```
C:\>net helpmsg 1326
Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Linux, then the rough equivalent to Windows' [`LogonUser` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is [`peercred`](http://welz.org.za/notes/on-peer-cred.html), as in `SO_PEERCRED`. (Thanks to Grawity on Super User [peercred](https://superuser.com/a/1060418/173513)).